# How do you wait for a selector, but only for a specific time period in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm scraping data from youtube and trying to get the number of comments. I'm trying to grab the element that contains the value, but in case the comments are disabled for a video, that element doesn't exist at all and `waitForSelector()` waits, I think, for about 30 seconds before ending the program. How can I tell puppeteer to wait for that element for, say, 5 seconds and if it doesn't exist, move on with the rest of the code?

Here's the code that I'm using-

```
await page.waitForSelector("yt-formatted-string.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer")
let commentCount = await (await (await page.$("yt-formatted-string.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer")).getProperty("textContent")).jsonValue()
```

Comment: So you want to wait for 5 sec instead of 30 sec?

Comment: according to the docs https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserwaitfortargetpredicate-options you can set timeout option in `waitForSelector`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Below code you can try for waiting -

`await page.waitForSelector(yourSelector, {timeout: TIMEOUT});`

*Ex:*

`await page.waitForSelector(yourSelector, {timeout: 5000});`

*UPDATED:*

To catch `timeouterror` and do something -

```
const {TimeoutError} = require('puppeteer/Errors');

try {
  await page.waitForSelector(yourSelector, {timeout: 5000});
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TimeoutError) {
    // Do something if this is a timeout.
  }
}
```

***Reference:***

New: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector

Old: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options

Comment: it worked, but it still stops execution when that timeout is done. how can I continue to execute the remaining code even though the timeout occurs?

Comment: Updated answer, please check

Comment: I did it using `page.evaluate()`, but thanks for the info on `TimeoutError`. I didn't know that. I'll also post the code as an answer here for anyone who might need it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Try code below, just add a `timeout` option

```js
try {
    await page.waitForSelector("yt-formatted-string.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer", {timeout: 5000 }); // 5s timeout
} catch (e) {
   // something wrong !!!!!!
}

let commentCount = await (await (await page.$("yt-formatted-string.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer")).getProperty("textContent")).jsonValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run it in the browser and include it in `page.evaluate()`. Here's the code if anyone needs it in the future -

```
while(true){
    if(await page.evaluate(async () => { // scroll till there's no more room to scroll or the comment element shows up
        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           var scrolledHeight = 0  
           var distance = 100 
           var timer = setInterval(() => {
               var scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight
               window.scrollBy(0, distance)
               scrolledHeight += distance
               if(scrolledHeight >= scrollHeight || document.querySelector("yt-formatted-string.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer")){
                     clearInterval(timer)
                     resolve(true)
               }
           }, 500)
        })
    })){
        break
    }
}
let commentElement = await page.$("yt-formatted-string.count-text.style-scope.ytd-comments-header-renderer"), commentCount = null
if(commentElement !== null){
    commentCount = await (await commentElement.getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue()
}
```